# Crash while replacing NSFetchedResultsController for UICollectionView during CoreData updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UICollectionView that receives it's contents from a NSFetchedResultsController.
The data comes from multiple API-Endpoints (the design of the server is not in my hands).
The first call delivers meta-data and than for each entry (> 10.000) there has to be an API-Call to get the relevant data.

CollectionView can be filtered for several properties and each filter requires a different sectionNameKeyPath

So when a user changes the filtering, I will have to replace the current FRC with a new one. But when CoreData is updating then the app crashes with

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UICollectionView.m:4422
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 9 from section 0 which only contains 1 items before the update'
```

So is there any way to avoid that crash?

**EDIT:** Added code for NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate:

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
   _objectChanges = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   _sectionChanges = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
 didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
          atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
    forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{


   if (type == NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert || type == NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete) {
       NSMutableIndexSet *changeSet = _sectionChanges[@(type)];
       if (changeSet != nil) {
           [changeSet addIndex:sectionIndex];
       } else {
           _sectionChanges[@(type)] = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] initWithIndex:sectionIndex];
       }
   }

}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
      atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
     newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

   NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(type)];
   if (changeSet == nil) {
       changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       _objectChanges[@(type)] = changeSet;
   }

   switch(type) {
       case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
           [changeSet addObject:newIndexPath];
           break;
       case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
           [changeSet addObject:indexPath];
           break;
       case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
           [changeSet addObject:indexPath];
           break;
       case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
           [changeSet addObject:@[indexPath, newIndexPath]];
           break;
   }

}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{

   NSMutableArray *moves = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
   if ([moves count] > 0) {
       NSMutableArray *updatedMoves = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[moves count]];

       NSMutableIndexSet *insertSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
       NSMutableIndexSet *deleteSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
       for (NSArray *move in moves) {
           NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = move[0];
           NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = move[1];

           if ([deleteSections containsIndex:[oldIndexPath section]]) {
               if (![insertSections containsIndex:[newIndexPath section]]) {
                   NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
                   if (changeSet == nil) {
                       changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:newIndexPath, nil];
                       _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)] = changeSet;
                   } else {
                       [changeSet addObject:newIndexPath];
                   }
               }
           } else if ([insertSections containsIndex:[newIndexPath section]]) {
               NSMutableArray *changeSet = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
               if (changeSet == nil) {
                   changeSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:oldIndexPath, nil];
                   _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)] = changeSet;
               } else {
                   [changeSet addObject:oldIndexPath];
               }
           } else {
               [updatedMoves addObject:move];
           }
       }

       if ([updatedMoves count] > 0) {
           _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)] = updatedMoves;
       } else {
           [_objectChanges removeObjectForKey:@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
       }
   }

   NSMutableArray *deletes = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
   if ([deletes count] > 0) {
       NSMutableIndexSet *deletedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
       [deletes filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSIndexPath *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
           return ![deletedSections containsIndex:evaluatedObject.section];
       }]];
   }

   NSMutableArray *inserts = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
   if ([inserts count] > 0) {
       NSMutableIndexSet *insertedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
       [inserts filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSIndexPath *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
           return ![insertedSections containsIndex:evaluatedObject.section];
       }]];
   }

   UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;
   [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

       NSIndexSet *deletedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
       if ([deletedSections count] > 0) {
           [collectionView deleteSections:deletedSections];
       }

       NSIndexSet *insertedSections = _sectionChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
       if ([insertedSections count] > 0) {
           [collectionView insertSections:insertedSections];
       }

       NSArray *deletedItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete)];
       if ([deletedItems count] > 0) {
           [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:deletedItems];
       }

       NSArray *insertedItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert)];
       if ([insertedItems count] > 0) {
           [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:insertedItems];
       }

       NSArray *reloadItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate)];
       if ([reloadItems count] > 0) {
           [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:reloadItems];
       }

       NSArray *moveItems = _objectChanges[@(NSFetchedResultsChangeMove)];
       for (NSArray *paths in moveItems) {
           [collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:paths[0] toIndexPath:paths[1]];
       }
   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       [[self refreshControl] endRefreshing];

   }];

   _objectChanges = nil;
   _sectionChanges = nil;

}
```

Comment: how are you handling the delegate callbacks? just reloading or trying to animate individual changes?

Comment: I tried both
I use performBatchUpdates: in controllerDidChangeContent and in the block I process two mutableDictionaries for itemChanges and sectionChanges.

But for testing I also tried simple "reloadData" in controllerDidChangeContent.

Comment: show the code for your change processing and for how you're saving changes into core data

Comment: I added the FRC-DelegateCode above.

For inserting new Data:

What I do is:

- NSJSONSerialization converts the JSON-Data into a Dictionary
- Then I create a temporary NSMangedObjectContext (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType that uses the MainContexts PersistantStore)
- On the localContext I query for the MO that needs to be changed … if found I change is.
If all data is processed, I save the localContext and that triggers the merge with the MainContext

Comment: the key part here is that you save once per set of changes, and there's a delay between that happening and any more changes being made, so the changes have time to make it into the collection view

Answer (score 0):

While your batching code looks clever and efficient it's very difficult to ensure that the batch of changes are cogent. If any sections are inserted or deleted, or any items are moved then it's very, and i mean very, difficult to ensure that all other index paths are correct and refer to the appropriate item.

If there are any section insertions or deletions I'd just reload. If there are moved items and anything else at the same time I'd just reload. If you have multiple insertions and deletions in the same section at the same time it could work, it could refresh the screen with the wrong data.

You need to be really careful with composite changes to the sections and section contents in the collection.

You don't show any code for your FRC change, I guess it's unrelated. You should definitely reload when you switch.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood your "code for your change processing"

For FRC change I tried several things. At the moment before any FRC-Change happens I remove the delegate and set the current FRC to nil and even reload the CollectionView. Then simply create a new FRC

Comment: you have code for change processing saving into core data and in the FRC delegate methods, i asked for both, it's all good. by FRC change i mean switching between different FRC instances, and your description sounds ok

Comment: My problem is that even reloadData instead of batchUpdate will lead to a crash

Comment: how and when do you reload in this case, and what's the crash?

Comment: I tried reload on controllerDidChange and the weird thing is, the crash is the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117586/discussion-between-wain-and-matzelocal).